# How to get every single permutation of all substrings of a string?

Tags: python, string, algorithm, substring, permutation

I know how to get the permutations of just the plain string in python:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> perms = [''.join(p) for p in permutations('stack')]
>>> print perms
...
```

But how would I get the permutations of `'stac'`, `'stak'`, `'sack'`, `'stck'`, `'stc'`, `'st'`, and so forth? My desired output is:

```
>>> permutations('pet')
['pet', 'pte', 'ept', 'etp', 'tpe', 'tep', 'pe', 'ep', 'p', 'e', 't', 'pt', 'tp', 'et', 'te']
```

What I have so far:

```
def permutate(values, size):
  return map(lambda p: [values[i] for i in p], permutate_positions(len(values), size))

def permutate_positions(n, size):
  if (n==1):
    return [[n]]
  unique = []
  for p in map(lambda perm: perm[:size], [ p[:i-1] + [n-1] + p[i-1:] for p in permutate_positions(n-1, size) for i in range(1, n+1) ]):
    if p not in unique:
      unique.append(p)
  return unique

def perm(word):
  all = []
  for k in range(1, len(word)+1):
     all.append(permutate([' ']+list(word), k))
  return all
```

This runs as:

```
>>> perm('pet')
[[['t'], ['e'], ['p']], [['t', 'e'], ['e', 't'], ['e', 'p'], ['t', 'p'], ['p', 't'], ['p', 'e'], ['p', 'p']], [['t', 'e', 'p'], ['e', 't', 'p'], ['e', 'p', 't'], ['e', 'p', 'p'], ['t', 'p', 'e'], ['p', 't', 'e'], ['p', 'e', 't'], ['p', 'e', 'p'], ['t', 'p', 'p'], ['p', 't', 'p'], ['p', 'p', 't'], ['p', 'p', 'e']]]
>>>
```

However, it has a bunch of list of lists, and with values like ['p', 'p', 't']!

How do I do this? ANy help is appreciated.

Comment: There are several such examples on this site.  Try searching.

Comment: Take a look at [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

Comment: You mean *"every single permutation of all substrings of a string"*

Comment: By the way, should we assume the letters are distinct so you don't need to consider duplicate substrings? (Think of 'assess').

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is one way of doing it with [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
from itertools import permutations
s = 'pet'
print [''.join(p) for i in range(1, len(s)+1) for p in permutations(s, i)]
```

Output:

```
['p', 'e', 't', 'pe', 'pt', 'ep', 'et', 'tp', 'te', 'pet', 'pte', 'ept', 'etp', 'tpe', 'tep']
```